# Java seems to ignore global "update" setting in registry

Tags: windows, java, update

I have installed JRE 1.7.0_04-b22. I disabled the "update" setting in administrator - update requests disappeared, but in ordinary user's account it is nagging me about updates and I can't turn it off. The "update" tab is grayed out. When I run javacpl.exe with administrator rights, it changes the global setting:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\NotifyDownload
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\NotifyInstall
```

but then can't use it in ordinary user account.